# What is the focus of Tumblr's API and get an API key?

Tags: ajax, api, tumblr, api-key

I am trying to understand Tumblr's API (v2), but i think that the documentation is bit confusing for beginners.

What i am doing right now, is make simple and public scripts, that means are only javascript (frontend), for example a script that detect if the user has already like a post in the blog itself. For that reason, i need to make ajax requests, for all the info that is just available using the API. BUT... what the documentation make me to understand, is that the focus of the API is for make apps (like an Android app, i think), but nothing about make something like i want, and for use the API, i need to register an app, and in that way i will get the API key for use the API, but in fact i will not make a app.

Also, the API key is something secret, but i must insert it in the script code (am i wrong?), that means it can't be a public script because anybody can see my API key.

Considering that i am not doing something in a personal server (no PHP, no backend...), and my focus is just the frontend (but using ajax to access to tumblr's databases), so... what i should create with the Tumblr API, and what shouldn't? Can i use it for what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your making the query using theme operators, use the API.

For each `script` you create, for example, the user liking a post on the current blog, you would register it as an app, and it would have its on unique key. You would then distribute the script, with this key included.

I understand the confusion. As your `scripts` are not technically apps, but from experience, it seems to be the way to go.

Hope that helps!

Comment: oh i see... but i have a question yet: Ok, i will use the API considering i will not technically make an app, but so... what should i fill in the app string ("set here your Google play/App store URL") while i am getting the API key? Should i set it in blank?

Comment: @Yavierre yep, as well as the default callback URL I set to `/`.

Comment: Hard to see that i must register every script for every "use", but anyway i am happy to read that, thanks!

Comment: @Yavierre excellent! I would love to see what you come up with, maybe help out. Send me a ping if you are interested :D

Comment: well... i don't know about that of "send a ping", but yes, i am interested :D